# CMD filepath input to CBC solver is not working

Tags: cmd, solver

I am trying to run a **solver** (CBC) through the **CMD** interface.

The following line works and executes properly when I put the input mps file into the same directory as the solver:

```
CMD>> "solver_path\solver.exe" "input.mps"
```

However, I want to run the same code as above but give the solver a pathname for the input.txt file. i.e.

```
CMD>> "solver_path\solver.exe" "C:/.../input.mps"
```

In the above intance the solver is not able to open the file, I do not understand why this is happening as

```
CMD>>"C:/.../input.mps"
```

opens the file so it definitely exists and can be opened.

Any advice would be much appreciated.